# MVC Form submit ORDERMetadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ORDER model that contains over 20 fields from my .edmx.  I created a new model ORDERMetadata with fewer fields so I could customize the properties in my View.  When I try compile
it gives me am error.

**ERRORS:**

> The best overloaded method match for'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(Mvc5.Models.ORDER)' has some invalid arguments

And

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata' to 'Mvc5.Models.ORDER'

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ORDERMetadata order)
{
    try 
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ORDERS.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }                                       

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {              
        ViewBag.Error = ex.ToString();
    }

    return View(order);

}
```

Comment: If your passing `ORDERMetadata` to your view the your view should have `@model ORDERMetadata` and the POST method should be `public ActionResult Create(ORDERMetadata model)`

Comment: stephen, I get the following compile errors when changing it to that. Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Mvc5.Models.ORDER>.Add(Mvc5.Models.ORDER)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata' to 'Mvc5.Models.ORDER'

Comment: You need initialize a new `Order` then map the properties from your posted view model `ORDERMetadata` to `Order` then save. The problem you currently have is that if the model is invalid you return `View(order);` but the view expects type `ORDERMetadata` not typeof `Order`

Comment: I changed this line to this, is there anything else I need to do? public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Order_Number,Order_Type,Order_Date")] ORDERMetadata order)

Comment: You shouldn't need need the `Bind` attribute since if you have created a view model then those are the only properties that should be in the model. If you are still having problems then you need to update your question with the new code and include the view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ORDERMetadata model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  try
  {
    Order order = new Order();
    // map properties from your view model to the data model
    order.Order_Number = model.Order_Number;
    ... // other properties
    db.ORDERS.Add(order);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }                                       
  catch (Exception ex)
  {              
    ViewBag.Error = ex.ToString();
    return View(model);
  }
}
```